# Puzzle: To escape the check of typeid

Tags: c++, typeid

I formed a nice interview question by chance. :)

```
template<typename T>
bool foo (T obj)
{
  if(typeid(T) == typeid(obj))
    return false;
  return true;  // <-- execute this
}
```

You have to call (only above mentioned) `foo()` in such a way that it returns `true`. Conditions are,

1. Cannot edit or overload `foo()` or `typeid`
2. No platform specific hacks allowed
3. No `#define` allowed

Comment: Might this not be better placed at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Not suggesting that it's not allowed (didn't flag it for that matter). Like the question. Was just wondering.

Comment: @Bart, anyways, I have put the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main ()
{
  typedef char C[1];
  foo<C>(0);  // returns true;
}
```

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033970/passing-typedef-fixed-sized-array-by-value) to know the explanation of this answer and root of this question.

Comment: Nice. A oneliner `foo<char[1]>(0);` will do too.

Comment: I think `foo<char[1]>("abc")` is a more useful way to communicate what's happening to S.O. readers... one quirk at a time ;-).

Answer (score 11):

```
#include <cassert>

struct B { virtual ~B() {} };

int main()
{
    struct : B {} x;
    assert(foo<B&>(x));
}
```

Action is [over there](http://www.ideone.com/yVGtW).

Comment: @Alexandre, +1 good one, but I missed to mention runtime polymorphism part. I was expecting different answer

Comment: @iammilind: what did you expect ? `typeid(T)` will be resolved at compile time if `T` is known, as well as `typeid(obj)` if `obj` is not polymorphic (its static type will be used).

Comment: Could you kindly explain a little bit?

Comment: @Dante: sure, what part don't you understand ?

Comment: @Alexandre C. What is `&` used for?

Comment: @Dante Jiang: `typeid` will return *polymorphic* type information *only if* it is applied to a reference type. If I replace `B&` by `B`, then 1) `x` will be sliced when passed to `foo`, turning it into an actual `B`, and 2) `typeid(obj)` will return the *static* type of `obj` if `obj` is not of reference type (in this case, `T`).

Comment: @Alexandre, I have posted the answer.