# const array of fixed size const array as argument of a method in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, constants, argument-passing

Following my question about [passing array as const argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543625/passing-an-array-as-a-const-argument-of-a-method-in-c), I am trying to figure out how to write a method where the argument is a const array of fixed size const array. The only writable thing would be the content of these arrays.

I am thinking about something like this:

```
template <size_t N>
void myMethod(int* const (&inTab)[N])
{
    inTab = 0;       // this won't compile
    inTab[0] = 0;    // this won't compile
    inTab[0][0] = 0; // this will compile
}
```

The only problem in this solution is that we don't know the first dimension. 
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

[Edit]

I don't want to use std::vector or such dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: `The only writable thing would be the content of these arrays.` and `the argument is a const array ` do not go well together

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but passing an array of arrays is done like this: `template <size_t N, size_t M> void myMethod(int (&inTab)[N][M])`.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: It makes perfect sense: it's a constant array of pointers to writable arrays.

Comment: However, you still have to pass an continuous block of data to this method, right?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, hmm, I thought `where the argument is a const array of fixed size const array` means " a const array of const arrays"...

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Oh yes, I didn't notice the second "const". Presumably that's a typo, since the code clearly uses pointers to writable arrays.

Comment: @Spook: that's the point, I don't want to be oblige to pass a  continuous block of data to this method.

Comment: @MikeSeymour & SingerOfTheFall: sorry if I was not clear. I want `inTab` and all `inTab[]` as const but all `inTab[][]` writable. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD: See my answer below. Presuming you only really want to achieve line 2 and 3 in your code, how about just removing that `const`?

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD What I meant is, that you can only pass statically allocated arrays with their sizes known at compile time, which are, actually, continuous blocks of memory :)

Comment: @avasopht: I think I did explain well what I needed. My code is exactly what I need except that it keeps the first dimension unknown.

Comment: @Spook: so this means that I can not do better than I wrote?

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD: So what you're saying is that you want to repoint `inTab`? And no, you never explicitly stated the need to repoint `inTab`, you actually said that you only wanted to write to the array's contents (not making mention of the array pointers) Which is contrary to line 1 and 2. And by line 1 and 2, I mean the `inTab=0;` and `inTab[0] = 0;`. Perhaps my error was referencing the lines inside the functions, which would have really been lines 4 and 5, sorry.

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD That mostly depends on your needs. Take into consideration, that static arrays are placed on stack rather than on heap (stack's size is tightly restricted), they cannot be resized, and the compiler will create another function for each set of dimensions you will use in your code. I think, that using standard containers like std::vector or std::array might prove more flexible and easy to further expand. But I'm quite a fan of OOp and I don't like C-style programming, so take my comments with a grain of salt :)

Comment: @avasopht: We are still misunderstanding ourselves. I want a compiler error when writing `inTab = 0` and `inTab[0] = 0`.

Comment: Oh lol, yes that's fine then ^_^

Answer (score 5):

If both dimensions are known at compile time, then you could use a 2-dimensional array (in other words, an array of arrays) rather than an array of pointers to arrays:

```
template <size_t N, size_t M>
void myMethod(int (&inTab)[N][M])
{
    inTab = 0;       // this won't compile
    inTab[0] = 0;    // this won't compile
    inTab[0][0] = 0; // this will compile
}

int stuff[3][42];
myMethod(stuff); // infers N=3, M=42
```

If either dimension is not known at runtime, then the arrays presumably need to be dynamically allocated. In that case, consider using `std::vector` both to manage the allocated memory and to keep track of the size.

Answer (score 0):

The reference prevents line 4 (`inTab = 0;`), because you've made `inTab` a reference. The const prevents line 5 (`inTab[0] = 0;`) because an `inTab` pointer is const.